# Getting table name with the select query of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the table name within the sql query that I am writing to get data from the same table, for example

Table_one

[image]

TABLE_TWO

[image]

So while doing this query

```
Select * from table_one UNION Select * from table_two
```

the result that i get is the data of two tables in one table like this:

[image]

But what I need that one more column to come in the table to see the data is coming from which table as following
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all`:

```
select id, name, age, 'table_one' as tabel_name
from table_one
union all
select id, name, age, 'table_two'
from table_two
```